# Wrong Button Clicking in Jetpack Compose Web

Tags: jetpack-compose-web

Clicking the `foo` button the second and subsequent times causes the code for the `bar` button to be executed. It seems related to the collection that I `map` to `P` elements.

```
fun main() {
    renderComposableInBody {
        val words = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }
        words.map { P { Text(it) }}
        Button(attrs = { onClick { words.add("foo") } }) { Text("foo") }
        Button(attrs = { onClick { words.add("bar") } }) { Text("bar") }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. Perhaps it has been fixed in the recent versions of Compose.

Comment: @Serge thank you for trying to replicate and thereby verifying that it's been fixed. Good to know as it motivates me to resume elegant coding!